# Using the return from a function outside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am quite new to programming, and I am starting with Python (version 3). At the minute I am trying to understand functions. I have a simple calculator for working out a persons pay, including over time. The function computes the over time.

```
def computeOvertime(h,r):
    standardHrs = 40
    overTimeRate = r * 1.5
    overTimeHrs = h - standardHrs
    overTimePay = overTimeHrs * overTimeRate
    return overTimePay

h = float(input("Enter Hours:"))
rate = input("Enter Rate:")
r = float(rate)

basicPay = 40 * r

p = computeOvertime(h,r)

totalPay = overTimePay + basicPay
print(totalPay)
```

When I run this, I get an error stating the name `overTimePay` is not defined.

I thought when I returned the `oveTimePay` from the function, I could use it outside the function.

I hope someone can give me some advice.

Comment: Just a note to say that your function is well written, with several explaining variables. If you had written it like this: `def computeOvertime(h,r): return (h - 40)* (r * 1.5)` it would be functionally the same, but no local variables. You should write functions as you have done, but you should think of them as I have written. No local variables to confuse the thought.

Comment: Also note that there is no need for the local `p`. Do this: `totalPay = computeOverTime(h, r) + basicPay`

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for the feedback, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did:

```
p = computeOvertime(h,r)
```

The local variable overTimePay (local to your function) was returned and assigned to the variable p. Try using:

```
totalPay = p + basicPay
```

Hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: Of course! Thank you. Couldn't see the forest because of the trees I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `overTimePay` is a local variable in the `computeOvertime` funcion. So if you want to use it as a global, you can:

```
def computeOvertime(h,r):
    standardHrs = 40
    overTimeRate = r * 1.5
    overTimeHrs = h - standardHrs
    global overTimePay
    overTimePay = overTimeHrs * overTimeRate
```

But in normal, I usually do like this

```
def computeOvertime(h,r):
    standardHrs = 40
    overTimeRate = r * 1.5
    overTimeHrs = h - standardHrs
    overTimePay = overTimeHrs * overTimeRate
    return overTimePay

p = computeOvertime(h,r)
totalPay = p + basicPay
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember you saved computeOvertime result to P?  Use that.

```
p = computeOvertime(h,r)

totalPay = p + basicPay
print(totalPay)
```

Comment: Thank you! Stared at the for a while, and didn't make the connection. Thanks.

Comment: @o.fithcheallaigh do give an upvote if my answer helped you :)

Comment: I tried to, but it seems I don't have > 15 reputation points, so it isn't recorded. When I do, I will come back and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

if you are collecting the returned value in 'p' then why you have to use 'OverTimePay'.

Just use `p+basicPay`

Or declare OverTimePay as a global variable using keyword global. And one more thing using global variable in this way is not a good thing. So just use local variable in which you have stored the returned result.

Comment: Please amend this to say that using globals in this way is a *bad thing*.

Comment: That was quick. Thanks.